# Change content of views_field_view field using hook_views_pre_render

Tags: 7, views

I am using the [views_view_field](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module for embedding a view inside another view.

I want to concatenate some text with that field in `hook_views_pre_render` based on a condition.

But when I printed the `$view->result` array, that field is not there.

So How can I do this?

Comment: Is that other field hidden in the views UI?

Comment: Seeing that you're embedding a view, it might be that the view field isn't available yet. Did you try to run the pre_render on the view you are embedding instead? Another option could be to create a template for the embedded view field.

Comment: @NoSssweat which field? If you are talking about the view field then No, it is not hidden.

Comment: @seroton I need the parent view field value for the condition therefore I can't use pre_render on the child view.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [template_preprocess_views_view_fields](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_fields/7.x-3.x)

If you still can't access that field there then:

- Ditch [views_view_field](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view)
- Add a "custom text field" (their field_name will be `nothing`).
- In [template_preprocess_views_view_fields](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_fields/7.x-3.x) programmatically add view to this "custom text field".

/sites/all/themes/THEMENAME/**template.php**

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];
  foreach ($view->field as $id => $field) {
    if ($something == 'some condition') {
      $vars['fields']['nothing']->content = 'some string' . '<br><br>' . 
        views_embed_view('view_name', 'view_machine_name', $contextual_filter_value);
    }
    else {
      $vars['fields']['nothing']->content = views_embed_view('view_name', 'view_machine_name', $contextual_filter_value);
    }
  }
}
```

If your view does not need a contextual filter, then it's:

views_embed_view('view_name', '[view_machine_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsMjX.jpg)');